# Applications of real numbers being a vector space over the rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, applications, hamel-basis

What applications are there of the fact that the real numbers form a vector space over the rational numbers?

Vector spaces over the rational numbers appear to have uses in number theory.

The motivation for this question comes from Dietrich's answer to this question: [Applications of uncountability of the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471113/applications-of-uncountability-of-the-real-numbers). That question asks why it is useful to know that the real numbers are uncountable. This was motivated by an open problem. The most popular answer to that question mentioned the fact that the real numbers form an infinite-dimensional vector space over the rational numbers. This has prompted me to ask why this fact is again useful.

Comment: The google search ["Hamel basis" + pathology](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hamel+basis%22+pathology) should give you more than enough applications.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If you can summarise one of the thousands of paper you refer to below, it would make a good answer

Comment: @jkabrg: I think the best thing would be to use google scholar with selected search terms (e.g. "Hamel basis", "Cauchy" + "functional equation", etc.) and an area of math or topic you know something about. Maybe include "counterexample" also as a search word. Also, I'm very busy right now with some work that I'm trying to get done in the next 8-10 hours.

Answer (score 4):

There are nonlinear real functions that satisfy [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation) $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best known application is the construction of a Hamel basis (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html ), which allows you to solve the Cauchy functional equation (over the reals): $$f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y) $$
If $f$ is taken to be over the rationals then $f(x)=cx$ is a solution for each $c\in {\mathbb R}$, but if $f$ is taken over the reals then the Hamel basis is used to show that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I guess the follow-up question is why non-linear solutions to this functional equation are useful. Not that they need to be

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question (or search the site for it first).  It's interesting as a functional equation in it's own right, and there's a connection with the Axiom of Choice in there as well :)

Comment: @jkabrg: *why non-linear solutions to this functional equation are useful* --- Among the thousands (yes, thousands) of papers that have been published on this, a particularly well known paper is [*Connected and disconnected plane sets and the functional equation* $f(x) + f(y) = f(x+y)$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183504138) by F. B. Jones.