Are there any theorems that use the uncountability of the reals in their proof?
Can we use the uncountability of the reals as a tool to prove any theorem? Can we use this to calculate anything? Suppose I was trying to convince a pragmatist that uncountability is useful.

I'm trying to avoid theorems about non existence, for example.

Something which is so simple and easy to prove can't not have important consequences.

The answers are good, I admit, this may be too abstract for me. Can we calculate anything using this idea? I'm fishing for something for more easily applicable.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376833/473276 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471113/473276 . I think most serious applications will inevitably be somewhat abstract, I'm afraid.

You can show the algebraic numbers are countable, hence transcendental numbers exist.
(An aside - Liouville proved the existence of transcendental numbers only 30 years before Cantor's uncountable proofs)

Most reals are irrational.  The rationals are countable, the reals are not, so the measure of the rationals is zero.
